# Conditional Formatting is populating when I don't have the value in the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

I am having an issue on column O shows green when I added conditional formatting but it suppose to show when there is a value greater than 30. There is no value in the cell but it's showing green.

How can I have the conditional formatting but also not have t populate green until there is a value
[image]

Comment: `""` is greater than 30, so you need a rule based on a formula that checks, for example, whether the `LEN` of the cell is `>0`, or using `ISNUMBER`.

Comment: How would I add that in my current formula?

Comment: Use a rule based on a formula, something like `=AND(ISNUMBER($O1),$O1>30)`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example Image]

You do not need to change your formulas.

As seen in my Example Image link above, do the following:

Create two conditional formatting rules for the range of cells.

The first rule is for blanks and has no actual change in fill color. Check the "Stop If True" box. If a blank or `""` is found it will *change* the formatting to the standard formatting.

The second rule is for cell values greater than 30. If a blank or `""` is not found it will go to this second rule which actually changes the fill color when the value > 30.

The order of the rules matters. In this order, the blanks are dealt with first and the values over 30 are dealt with second.